# Freeradius in debugging mode error

Tags: debugging, ubuntu, server, radius, freeradius

**Im trying to run freeradius in debugging mode( freeradius -X) but I get an error. the error is "Failed binding to authentication address * port 1812: Address already in use /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf[240]: Error binding to port for 0.0.0.0 port 1812"

Why I'm I getting this error?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to stop all freeradius ID

## ps –A | grep freeradius

To get process ID of freeradius

## kill -9 freeradius-PID

Start FreeRadius again

sudo /etc/init.d/freeradius start

Answer (score 0):

Another instance of FreeRADIUS is running and bound to UDP port 1812. `killall radiusd`

Comment: When I type "killall radiusd" I get "radiusd: no process found".

Comment: ``killall freeradius`` (if on debian or ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Run the command **'killall freeradius'** ( if on ubuntu ) 
Then,Restart the service, **'/etc/init.d/freeradius restart'**
and stop the service, **'/etc/init.d/freeradius stop'**
Now, if you run the command **'freeradius -X'**
you will not get the error.

Comment: if that doesn't work try these commands: 'service freeradius restart' and then  'service freeradius stop' and then run 'freeradius -X' command.Definitely, you will not get any error.

Answer (score 0):

You can running

```
killall freeradius && freeradius -X
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the freeradius using below command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/freeradius stop
```

And then you can start again using below command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/freeradius start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the debugging using the init script interface

```
sudo /etc/init.d/freeradius stop
sudo /etc/init.d/freeradius debug-threaded
```